# glusterfs unable to read gsyncd status file

Tags: ssh, replication, glusterfs, tune2fs

## Goal

I wanted to try glusterfs geo-replication in some virtualboxes on my computer for later use distributed on multiple sites.

## Configuration

I installed glusterfs 3.6 on ubuntu 32bit servers like this:

```
add-apt-repository -y ppa:gluster/glusterfs-3.6
apt-get update -qq
apt-get install glusterfs-server -y
```

In `/etc/hosts` on every virtualbox is an entry like this so that i can use hostnames:

```
192.168.1.1 ivymaster.com
192.168.1.2 ivyslave2.com
192.168.1.3 ivyslave1.com
```

## Setup

First I created and startet a volume on master (`force` to create on rootfs):

```
gluster volume create master ivymaster.com:/var/glustermaster/ force
gluster volume start master
```

Works fine. I setup passwordless root login with `ssh-copy-id` and logged in one time manually to check if this is setup correct and the host is stored in `known_hosts`.

I was not able to setup synchronisation into a directory like described in [Geo-Replication Terminology - Understanding the URI](https://github.com/Kaushikbv/Geo-replication-Documentaion/blob/master/doc.md). Creation of geo-replication failed with URI problem.

```
gluster volume geo-replication master ivyslave2.com:/var/slave2 start
 Staging failed on localhost. Please check the log file for more details.
```

## Errors after creating successfully replication

Logfile contains entries like `Invalid slave name`, `Unable to store slave volume name`, `Unable to fetch slave or confpath details`.

When I create a volume on `ivyslave2.com` and create geo-replication with usage of this volume, this works:

```
 gluster volume geo-replication master ivyslave2.com::slave2 create push-pem force
  Creating geo-replication session between master & ivyslave2.com::slave2 has been successful
```

Unfortunately, `gluster volume geo-replication master ivyslave2.com::slave2 status` sais that the status of the replication is faulty.

```
MASTER NODE      MASTER VOL    MASTER BRICK                SLAVE                    STATUS    CHECKPOINT STATUS    CRAWL STATUS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ivyVirtMaster    master       /var/glusterfs_master_nv        ivyslave2.com::slave2    faulty    N/A                  N/A
```

After executing this command, logfile on master contains `Using passed config template(/var/lib/glusterd/geo-replication/master_ivyslave2.com_slave2/gsyncd.conf).`, `Unable to read gsyncd status file`, `Unable to read the statusfile for /var/glusterfs_master_nv brick for  master(master), ivyslave2.com::slave2(slave) session`.

### Issue with tune2fs?

Logfile on slave contains `Received status volume req for volume slave2`, `tune2fs exited with non-zero exit status`, `failed to get inode size`.

Is this the volume on slave faulty? Is this issue related to 
[tune2fs exited with non-zero exit status](https://www.mail-archive.com/gluster-users@gluster.org/msg19454.html)? How can a geo replication be setup without a volume? Is there something wrong in geo replication configuration?

**Relation**
This is a duplicate of [post in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670427/glusterfs-unable-to-read-gsyncd-status-file).